# Divide cells in row if it contains specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to see if range "A2:A500" contains the text "US", if it does I want to divide cell C and B in that specifik row. So for example if Cell A5 contains US then only B5/C5 should be divided. Is this possible?

my formula

```
=IF(A2:A500="US*"; "$B2/$C500";"")
```

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(A2:A50;"US*");$C17/$B17; "")

I changed it to this, but now I gave it the "right" cells can it by itself find "C17/B17"

Comment: The cells in A2:A500 could have any string with US at the begining? like this USLJLJLJLJO???

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, with one assumption(1) there will only be one instance of "US", if any. Technically if there are multiple cells with "US", it could be done, but it isn't clear what you'd want to do in that case (divide the sum of those B rows by the sum of those C rows?)

First, we will use the MATCH function to determine if there is an instance of "US" in column A:

```
=MATCH("US*",A:A,0)
```

Then, we will nest that formula inside an INDEX formula, to pull the values from columns B & C, from the row which we determined from the MATCH function.

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("US*",A:A,0))/INDEX(C:C,MATCH("US*",A:A,0))
```

Finally, we will nest the entire formula inside of an IFERROR function. This will allow us to show a different value, if an error arises for any reason:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH("US*",A:A,0))/INDEX(C:C,MATCH("US*",A:A,0)),"")
```

Note - this will also show an error if, for example, there is a match for US, but the value in that row for column C is a 0 - because it will create a divide by zero error. If you want to see that a divide by 0 error may exist, you will need to restructure your formula so that it first checks for a match in column A, and then calculates the division, like so:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("US*",A:A,0)),"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH("US*",A:A,0))/INDEX(C:C,MATCH("US",A:A,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I seen to be very simple, just take the first two characters of the cell to test if is US no matter what the string has using `LEFT` formula

Well you have this:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|    | Col A | Col B | Col C |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | AG    |    26 |    17 |
|  2 | JH    |    25 |    22 |
|  3 | UY    |    16 |    24 |
|  4 | JH    |    11 |    11 |
|  5 | HY    |    28 |    14 |
|  6 | BV    |    25 |    27 |
|  7 | US    |    15 |    18 |
|  8 | HY    |    30 |    21 |
|  9 | HN    |    21 |    22 |
| 10 | UY    |    20 |    12 |
| 11 | BV    |    10 |    23 |
| 12 | TD    |    24 |    12 |
| 13 | US    |    30 |    26 |
| 14 | UY    |    24 |    19 |
| 15 | BG    |    15 |    29 |
| 16 | TF    |    30 |    23 |
| 17 | US    |    27 |    24 |
| 18 | PO    |    13 |    14 |
| 19 | US    |    20 |    14 |
| 20 | MN    |    28 |    20 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

And inside the cells D1:D20 you write this

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,2)="US",B1/C1,0)
```

This is:

IF the first two characters of the cell `A#`(Cells from column A, any number) are equial to `"US"` `(IF(LEFT(A1,2)="US")`, `THEN` divide B between C (the Same row), otherwise give a `0`

Result:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    | Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | AG    |    26 |    17 | 0.000 |
|  2 | JH    |    25 |    22 | 0.000 |
|  3 | UY    |    16 |    24 | 0.000 |
|  4 | JH    |    11 |    11 | 0.000 |
|  5 | HY    |    28 |    14 | 0.000 |
|  6 | BV    |    25 |    27 | 0.000 |
|  7 | US    |    15 |    18 | 0.833 |
|  8 | HY    |    30 |    21 | 0.000 |
|  9 | HN    |    21 |    22 | 0.000 |
| 10 | UY    |    20 |    12 | 0.000 |
| 11 | BV    |    10 |    23 | 0.000 |
| 12 | TD    |    24 |    12 | 0.000 |
| 13 | US    |    30 |    26 | 1.154 |
| 14 | UY    |    24 |    19 | 0.000 |
| 15 | BG    |    15 |    29 | 0.000 |
| 16 | TF    |    30 |    23 | 0.000 |
| 17 | US    |    27 |    24 | 1.125 |
| 18 | PO    |    13 |    14 | 0.000 |
| 19 | US    |    20 |    14 | 1.429 |
| 20 | MN    |    28 |    20 | 0.000 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Info for [LEFT and LEFTB functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c) and the [IF Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

**Edit #1**

On my example, just put two characters in the columns A, but if the cells of column A has any string, and any of that strings has US at the begining, the formula must divide `B/C`, because of the `LEFT` function, that take  the first tw characters of the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myRange As Excel.Range
    For i = 2 To 500
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "US" Then
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
    myRange.Select
    Selection.UnMerge
    End If
    Next
    End Sub


EDIT - ops, it contains US

Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sToCheck As String
Dim myRange As Excel.Range
For i = 2 To 500
sToCheck = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
If InStr(1, sToCheck, "US", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
myRange.Select
Selection.UnMerge
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. but is it possible to have that as a formula?

Comment: i think it's not possible.